# PostgreSQL split string with comma seraprated ints into comma separated ints

Tags: sql, postgresql, split, type-conversion

I got "1,2,3,4,5" as a param. I want to use it in WHERE something NOT IN (1,2,3,4,5)
How to convert it inside procedure?

Answer (score 2):

You can convert it to an array:

```
where something <> ALL (string_to_array('1,2,3,4,5', ',')::int[])
```

assuming that `something` is an integer.